# Authorize.net - Multi-currency - disabling currency code when sending money

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I have a issue processing multiple currencies in Drupal 7 Commerce with Authorize.net Gateways (version 1.0 stable).

I have Canadian store and have 2 currencies setup for my site: US and CDN funds.

Our processor is Bluepay and I have established separate US and CDN accounts.

I have noticed there are no problems processing US payments during check out. However when checking out in Canadian Currency using a Canadian Credit Card Authorize.net rejects my transaction.

Authorize.net is stating I must turn off 'currency code' in order for Canadian funds to be accepted with their gateways.

Is there a way to disable currency code in Drupal 7 Commerce? Is this even recommended if using more than 1 currency? How do most people go about processing multiple currencies in Drupal 7 Commerce via Gateways and Processors?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the issue is that the currency code value is included or is it simply wrong? i.e. are you submitting a USD currency code to a CDN account? Note that in the [1.0 released earlier this month](http://drupal.org/node/1967546) we fixed a couple of issues pertaining to multi-currency usage. Does updating to this version allow transactions to process as expected?